# Why the DialogFragment didn't show?

Tags: java, android

Requirement is that when I open the switchbutton, the dialog will be show and to start fingerprint auth. In the FingerprintActivity.java, the dialog worked fine, but in the SettingListActivity.java, it didn't show! The code is the same, why didn't show? That's my problem, Thank you in advance!

FingerprintActivity.java

```
private void initDialog() {
    //show dialog to start fingerprint auth
    FingerPrintDialog fpDialog = new FingerPrintDialog();
    fpDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fpDialog");
    startFingerprintRecognitionUnlockScreen();
}
```

SettingListActivity.java

```
if (position == 3) {
    vh.switchBtn.setChecked(ConnData.isFingerPrint);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor fingerStatus = getSharedPreferences("finger", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    vh.switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            clickType = 1;
            isFingerOpen = isChecked;
            //switchbutton status
            if (isFingerOpen) {
                //hasn't fingerprint
                if (!manager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    new DialogMgr(SettingListActivity.this.getParent(), R.string.title_information, R.string.message_sure_start_finger, "") {
                        @Override
                        protected void onclick(View v) {
                            //intent to the system settings
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                            vh.switchBtn.setChecked(false);
                            super.onclick(v);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void oncancel(View v) {
                            //close button
                            vh.switchBtn.setChecked(false);
                            super.oncancel(v);
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    //show dialog to start fingerprint auth 
                    FingerPrintDialog fpDialog = new FingerPrintDialog();
                    fpDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fpOpenDialog");
                    mFingerprintCore = new FingerprintCore(SettingListActivity.this);
                    mFingerprintCore.setFingerprintManager(mResultListener);
                    mKeyguardLockScreenManager = new KeyguardLockScreenManager(SettingListActivity.this);
                    mFingerprintCore.startAuthenticate();

                    //open fingerprint and close gesture recognition
                    final LockPatternUtils lockPatternUtils = new LockPatternUtils(SettingListActivity.this);
                    lockPatternUtils.clearLock();
                    lockPatternUtils.saveLockFlag(false);
                    vh.switchBtn.setChecked(isFingerOpen);
                    fingerStatus.putString("isFingerPrint", "open");
                    fingerStatus.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: *why didn't show?* I wish I could say that the reason is because you have not formatted your code.  If you fix that someone may help you

Comment: To run the program, log shows “E/Dialog: show mWindowManager.addView RuntimeException”

Comment: we need to see full log

Comment: initDialog()  where you called